# jQuery plugin - Can't find download link

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, download

I can't find the download link from this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jgfeed

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Doesn't seem that stupid to me. I can't see any links either

Comment: you're not stupid at all, someone **royally** screwed up the plugins site make-over, not being able to download plugins (and easily) is the single biggest mistake they could have made...I have yet to figure out how to download one, other than finding it in google search results directly.

Comment: @Nick ah, so this is a global phenomenon! I was wondering because I had the same problem the other day... I assumed the plugin authors hadn't filed any files yet

Comment: http://bobcravens.com/demos/RssDemo/scripts/jquery.jgfeed-min.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to pull up [the google cache of the page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=cache:http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jgfeed&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1) to find it, here's a link:

http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jGFeed.zip

You're not stupid for asking, someone *really* needs to address this and fast, a plugins site you can't download from is <s>just about</s> completely useless.

If anyone else needs other plugins for now, I recommend finding the page, then gooling `cache:urlOfPluginPage` to get the cache version in the search results...not sure how long this will work as the caches expire, but it's better than nothing at the moment.

Comment: Well, the documentation still appears to be up, so not *completely* useless, though I usually get my documentation from elsewhere too.

Comment: @YiJiang - true, though for *many* plugins the documentation and demo is on the homepage anyway. I'm more frustrated that people took the effort to overhaul the plugins site with no real thought on this, it's a **major** oversight...and was better off left alone.

Comment: It doesn't look like any of the direct plugin links work anymore--I'm getting a "Page not found" on all of them.

The bobcravens.com link still works.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as an alternative, you can grab the file from somewhere else. Like, say here: http://bobcravens.com/demos/RssDemo/index.html

It's only .68kb, so I suppose you guys won't mind if I just post the whole thing here:

```
/*
 * jGFeed 1.0 - Google Feed API abstraction plugin for jQuery
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 jQuery HowTo
 *
 * Licensed under the GPL license:
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * URL:
 *   http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com
 *
 * Author URL:
 *   http://me.boo.uz
 *
 */
(function($){$.extend({jGFeed:function(url,fnk,num,key){if(url==null){return false;}var gurl="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&callback=?&q="+url;if(num!=null){gurl+="&num="+num;}if(key!=null){gurl+="&key="+key;}$.getJSON(gurl,function(data){if(typeof fnk=="function"){fnk.call(this,data.responseData.feed);}else{return false;}});}});})(jQuery);
```