# CSS media queries support in IE browser

Tags: jquery-plugins, media-queries

Please help me how can I use the media queries for IE browser? I have come across one jquery library: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/MediaQueries but I am unable to download this library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the download link: http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.mediaqueries.js_9.txt

The reason for the download link's disappearance was touched upon briefly in the discussion on this question: [jQuery plugin - Can't find download link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700022/jquery-plugin-cant-find-download-link)

As far as I can tell from the [plugin's homepage](http://protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/mediaqueries/), the plugin allows this behaviors, which already exists on other browsers, to be used as per normal.

If you want to know more about the use of media queries you can have a look at these documents:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/mediaqueries
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/safe-media-queries/

Comment: Thank you very much Yi Jiang. I have basic idea about the media queries and have used for the Firefox, chrome and opera browsers. I wanted to try for the IE browser for which I was not able to download the mediaqueries library. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 8):

I suggest not using javascript to simulate Media Queries.

Set up for mobile-first and see the absence of Media Queries as the first Media Query. Check out: [Rethinking the Mobile Web by Yiibu](http://www.slideshare.net/bryanrieger/rethinking-the-mobile-web-by-yiibu?from=ss_embed)

You can use

```
<!--[if (lte IE 8)&!(IEMobile)]>   <html lang="en" class="ieLte8"> <![endif]-->
```

So that you can use the selector .ieLte8 to do the same as you would for large displays via Media Queries.

Answer (score 0):

The plugins.jquery.com site no longer works.  If you go there it explains what happened and what they are trying to do to fix it.  I have searched BING for jquery.mediaqueries.js. But have not been able to locate it although I found many instances of people using it and swearing by it.

This javascript library css3-mediaqueries.js found at http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/ is supposed to be good for enabling this process though.